# How to find the normalized values within each level of a variable in R

Tags: r, normalization

I have a categorical variable B with 3 levels 1,2,3  also I have another variable A with some values.. sample data is as follows

```
A   B
22  1
23  1
12  1
34  1
43  2
47  2
49  2
65  2
68  3
70  3
75  3
82  3
120 3
.   .   
.   .   
.   .
.   .
```

All I want is say for every level of B ( say in 1) I need to calculate Val(A)-Min/Max-Min, similarly I need to reproduce the same to other levels (2 & 3)

Comment: It looks like you want to apply a certain function for the values in A, depending on the value of B. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes mickey, I want to normalize the values of A corresponding to the levels of B. like i said for each level there will be different min & max values if you notice. I want to create a new variable with such normalized values for entire A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `tapply` function:

```
x = read.table(text="A   B
22  1
23  1
12  1
34  1
43  2
47  2
49  2
65  2
68  3
70  3
75  3
82  3
120 3", header = TRUE)

y = tapply(x$A, x$B, function(z) (z - min(z)) / (max(z) - min(z)))

# Or using the scale() function
#y = tapply(x$A, x$B, function(z) scale(z, min(z), max(z) - min(z)))

cbind(x, unlist(y))
```

Not exactly sure how you want the output, but this should be a decent starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Solution using `dplyr`:

```
set.seed(1)
df=data.frame(A=round(rnorm(21,50,10)),B=rep(1:3,each=7))
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(B) %>% mutate(C= (A-min(A))/(max(A)-min(A)))
```

The output is like

```
# A tibble: 21 x 3
# Groups:   B [3]
       A     B      C
   <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
 1    44     1 0.0833
 2    52     1 0.417 
 3    42     1 0     
 4    66     1 1     
 5    53     1 0.458 
 6    42     1 0     
 7    55     1 0.542 
 8    57     2 0.784 
 9    56     2 0.757 
10    47     2 0.514 
# ... with 11 more rows
```